# How to get runtime substitutions in safe_substitute()?

Tags: python, shell

I am trying to execute a similar program where the user substitutes the template variables.

```
>>> from string import Template
>>> s = Template('$who likes $what')
>>> s.substitute(who='tim', what='kung pao')
'tim likes kung pao'
```

Example, I want the user to specify something like s.substitute($1=var1,$2=var2)
where my variables value pairs are obtained at runtime.

suppose the user inputs "john likes mary" and wants to substitute john with "jim" and mary with "mae"? I can get the template string during runtime but how can I assign the user's (john=jim,mary=mae) to my safe_substitute function?
Is it possible to do this in Python? Please dont hesitate to ask any further details.

Answer (score 0):

I meant to comment but I don't have enough rep yet:(

Would it work if you pass the user input as a dict to safe_substitute, like

```
>>> x = {'who':3, 'what':5}
>>> s.safe_substitute(x)
'3 likes 5'
```

?

Comment: But I want the user to enter this dictionary. Is it possible to get a set of keyvalue pairs from users and store it in a dict?

Comment: @Tania You can build the dict programmatically by parsing the keyvalue pairs from the user.